# yum install http://www.example.com/package.rpm vs. rpm -ivh http://www.example.com/package.rpm

Tags: centos, rhel, package-management, yum, rpm

What's the difference between those commands? Are there any advantages to you yum or rpm for the same task?

```
yum install http://go-cli.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/v6.12.2/cf-cli_amd64.rpm
```

vs.

```
rpm -ivh http://go-cli.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/releases/v6.12.2/cf-cli_amd64.rpm
```

System is CentOS7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yum` is a high-level package manager, able to solve *dependencies*.  This means that should `cf-cli_amd64.rpm` need other packages to be installed (as it happens in most cases), `yum` will automatically retrieve and install them without any hassle for the user.